# Progress Indicator color change depending on the section background color (fullpage.js)

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have a fullpage.js imported into my code and a progress bar indicator (div class="progress-section"). My question is, how do I change the progress bar indicator depending on the background color of a section? (E.g. progress indicator in black when section background color is white, and indicator in white when section bg is black.) I appreciate you all so much :)

I have added the code below:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Aaron</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-4rPgyv5iG0PZw8E+oRdfN/Gq+yilzt9rQ8Yci2jJ15rAyBmF0HBE4wFjBkoB72cxBeg63uobaj1UcNt/scV93w==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <!-- <header>
      <h4 class="logo">LIGHT</h4>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> -->
  <div class="progress-section">
    <div class="progress-bar-wrap" data-bg="fuchsia">
      <div class="progress-bar" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-num"></div>

  </div>

<div>




  <div id="fullpage">



    <div class="section one">
      Section ONE
    </div>

    <div class="section two">
      Section TWO
    </div>

    <div class="section three">
      Section THREE
    </div>

    <div class="section four">
      Section FOUR
    </div>

  </div>

  </div>


  <!-- Main Container Ends -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-gSf3NCgs6wWEdztl1e6vUqtRP884ONnCNzCpomdoQ0xXsk06lrxJsR7jX5yM/qAGkPGsps+4bLV5IEjhOZX+gg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
  </script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>



</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  background-color:#111111;
  color: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-section {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-bar-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
}

.white {
  background: white;

}


.one {
  background: gray;

}

.two {
  background: green;

}

.three {
  background: blue;

}

.four {
  background: purple;

}
#fullpage {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let progressSection = document.querySelector('.progress-section');
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
let progressNum = document.querySelector('.progress-num');

let x, y;


function updateProgressBar() {

  progressBar.style.height = `${getScrollPercentage()}%`;
  progressNum.innerText = `${Math.ceil(getScrollPercentage())}%`
  requestAnimationFrame(updateProgressBar)
}

function getScrollPercentage() {
  return ((window.scrollY) / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100)
};

updateProgressBar()


new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'LICENSE',
  autoScrolling: true,
  scrollBar: true,
})
```

Comment: I don't know anything about fullpage.js and it requires a key, so I can't even duplicate your code

Comment: Hi Steve the fullpage.js does not need a license unless using commercially. fullpage.js is basically a plugin which allows you to scroll smooth in a full page manner.

Comment: Interesting. Because when I try and run your code, I get the following error: `fullPage: Fullpage.js version 3 has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a 'licenseKey' option. Read about it here:` https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options

Comment: Hi Steve yup I did before when I used it without a license key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fullpage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) for that.

For example:

```css
/* On section 2 slide 0 */
.fp-viewing-page2-0 #nav{ 
   color: red
}
```

Here's a working example:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/VwbxbYR